How can I play an animation after the previous one is finished?
I have been trying the typewriter animation, and it went well!


.typewriter{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter .p1,.p2{
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
/*   margin-inline: auto; */
  overflow: hidden;
/* keeps on a single line */
  white-space: nowrap;
/* cursor */
  border-right: 3px solid;
/* steps = number of characters   */
  animation: typing 3s steps(22) forwards, blink 1s step-end infinite;
}

.typewriter .p2{
  font-size: 3rem;
  animation-delay: after previos;
}

@keyframes typing{
  from{
    width: 0;
  }
  
  to{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink{
  50%{
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
<div class = "typewriter">
  <div>
    <p class = "p1">Hello, Welcome to CodePen!</p>
    <p class = "p2">Let's get started!</p>
  </div>
</div>



But I am confused, about how to play the second line animation after the first one.
I am trying to create a typewriter animation for two specific paragraphs with different lengths and font sizes.
I want to customize the animation delay for each line so that the second paragraph starts typing only after the first finishes.
Solutions that use animation-delay or other modern techniques are welcome, but the existing duplicates do not address the unique requirements of this typewriter effect.

Animation delay will be useful here,but you'll want to have slightly different keyframes (in the sense of number of character steps) for the different lines as well.

If you want just css you can use animation-delay as A Haworth said. With javascript you can use eventlistener 'animationend'.

I have voted to reopen this question as the question marked as duplicate is not only very old and out of date but also does not explicitly tackle the two aspects here - starting the second line animation after the first is complete with ensuring the two lengths of the texts are dealt with well AND doing 'sensible' related animation of the caret (border).

Thank you for voting to reopen this question @AHaworth

My question is not related to transitions like those used in the duplicate question but focuses on animating a typewriter effect for multiple lines with different font sizes and delay logic for the second animation. Like animating divs sequentially, my problem has unique challenges related to overflow handling and custom keyframe sequences, which are not addressed in the suggested duplicate.

After going through the w3schools documentation and taking @AHaworth, @Yogi, and @alvinalvord's solutions, I have ended up with an answer myself. I would like to thank you all for your involvement.
The typewriter effect is a bit challenging when it comes to multiple elements with the conditions set by me:

should use only CSS.
should ensure simplicity and scalability.
should ensure the second and following elements stay hidden until the initial animation is finished playing.

By combining CSS properties like visibility, nth-child(n), animation-fill-mode I was able to achieve what I desired:


:root {
  --typing-effect: typing 2s steps(24, end);
  --blink-effect: blink 1s step-end; 
}

.typewriter {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.typewriter p {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures text doesn't overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Prevents text from wrapping */
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  /* Simulates a typing cursor */
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
}

/* Typing animation */
@keyframes typing {
  from { max-width: 0; }
  to { max-width: 100%; }
}

@keyframes blink { 50% { border-color: transparent; }}

/* Hide the cursor at the end. */
@keyframes hide { to { border-color: transparent; }}

/* Shows only after the previous animation is complete */
@keyframes show {
  from { visibility: hidden; }

  to { visibility: visible; }
}

/* Applying the animation */
p:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: var(--typing-effect), var(--blink-effect), hide 2s step-end;
  /* Adjust based on text length */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  max-width: calc(33*1.5rem);
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: show 0s 2s, var(--typing-effect) 2s, var(--blink-effect), hide 3.6s step-end;
  /* Adjust based on text length */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  max-width: calc(18*1.5rem);
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  animation: show 0s 4.2s forwards, var(--typing-effect) 4.2s, var(--blink-effect) infinite;
  max-width: calc(19*1.5rem);
}
<div class="typewriter">
  <div>
    <p>Hello, Welcome to stack overflow!</p>
    <p>Let's get started!</p>
    <p>Good Morning Peers!</p>
  </div>
</div>




The visibility:hidden property ensures subsequent lines remain hidden until their animations start.

The nth-child(n) selector synchronizes the animations for each line.

The animation-fill-mode: forwards keeps the lines visible after typing.


Edited:

The previous spacing issue has been solved by @alvinalvord
using max-width instead of width inside the typing @keyframes we can solve the cursor extending problem.

Setting separate max-width for each nth-child element we can complete the solution.



Regarding the issue related to the cursor extending to full width, you can instead use max-width for the typing keyframe. Then add the max widths of each p:nth-child, in this case, max-width: calc(33*1.5rem); for the first, max-width: calc(18*1.5rem); for the 2nd, and max-width: calc(19*1.5rem); for the third.

Thank you @alvinalvord this helps and I have edited my answer.

I modified one of your css class and added another keyframe and if my understanding is correct, you are looking for something like this?
.typewriter .p2{
  font-size: 3rem;
  animation: showAfter 3s, typing 3s steps(22) forwards 2.9s, blink 1s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes showAfter {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    99% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

A brief explanation is basically to hide .p2 for 3 seconds (same duration as .p1 animation) then play the typing animation before the full 3 seconds completes (2.9s delay).

This works perfectly! Thank you, @alvinalvord, for the detailed solution. Starting the second line animation after the first is complete. However, writing animations for each one individually might be challenging in a scenario with more than 10  elements. Do you think there's a way to make this reusable for larger sets of text?

Use CSS variables in the keyframes definitions for the step size and delay and a CSS calc for the width (ch units) and duration to cut down on the repetition a bit.
